# Star and bar problems with order of distribution not taking into consideration

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Star and bar problem takes order of distribution into consideration. For example,

> By star and bar analogy number of different sets of numbers $\{e_1,e_2\}$ such that $e_1+e_2=4$ is $\binom{4+2-1}{1}=5$. The five sets are {{0,4},{4,0},{1,3},{3,1},{2,2}}. This is like distributing 4 stars into two boxes (separated one bar) with order of how many stars a box gets taking into consideration.

However I want to find set of different numbers when distribution order is not taken into consideration. For example in above example, {0,4} and {4,0} will be considered only once. Same for {1,3} and {3,1}. Thus the number of different sets will be 3.

Can we have direct formula following some combinatorial analogy like star and bar for such problems without taking taking order of distribution into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

When order does not matter, the problem becomes harder to solve. This is an integer partition with $k$ parts ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory)#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts)). The number of ways to write $n$ as a sum of $k$ positive integers, $p_k(n)$, satisfies the recurrence $$p_k(n) = p_k(n-k) + p_{k-1}(n-1)$$ by considering two cases:

- the sum contains $1$ (and we can remove it to write $n-1$ as a sum of $k-1$ positive integers), and
- all terms of the sum are $\ge 2$ (and we can decrease all of them by $1$ to write $n-k$ as a sum of $k$ positive integers).

However, there's no closed-form solution.

In your case, since $0$ is allowed in the sum, the number of different sets is $p_k(n+k)$, instead.